# How to connect to an android device to Ubuntu by use Wifi-hotspot function of android to browse android files?

Tags: android, hot-spot, file-server

I would like to browse by Linux Mint the android device (Lollipop).
The android would be the server as an access point by wifi hotspot function, and the linux the cliend. I would like to browse by Mint file browser (Caja or any two panel file manager) the android files. I don't have root on it.
Is it possible? I don't want to use any play store app to this because every android has wi-fi access point option to work as a file server, hasn't it? If possible. Thank you for help!
I forgot to say hello. Hello everyone! :)

Comment: Your question is quite unclear – especially in the details. Could you please clarify how it relates to Ubuntu? Otherwise it's off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

There are few apps who can share Android files and folders like as Samba server. But they need your device to be rooted.

If your device isn't rooted (like mine) you can use [**ES File Explorer**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=bg) and its **Remote Manager** option.

1. Turn on WiFi Hotspot into your Android device. And connect the PC to it.
2. Run `ES File Explorer > Menu > Network > Remote Manager > Turn on`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

3. Type the ftp address listed on the screen into the PC's web browser.

[image]

4. Or browse the ftp via some (ftp capable) file browser. For example with **Nautilus**:

[image]

[image]

5. Or mount the ftp location to your file system.

   ```
   sudo apt install curlftpfs
   sudo mkdir /mnt/ftp
   sudo chown user:group /mnt/ftp
   curlftpfs 192.168.1.150:3721 /mnt/ftp/
   ```

[image]

You can read and write, but cannot delete files. That's it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
So not possible to browse files of phone without any special app, right?
I did every step your answer, but can't connect to server(ES file explorer) by chrome or nautilus.

Comment: Your solution is working fine for the second try. :) I didn't connect to the hot-spot  thats why didn't work first.